# Comparison between yield , FindAll and local variable

Tags: c#, .net, oop, collections, yield

I would like to apply a filter to a list of `Student` objects . I find three ways to do this:

**First Way**

By  the use of `FindAll`

```
List<Student> liste = Admin.GetStudentList().FindAll(x => x.Age > 20);
```

**Second Way**

A method which uses the `yield` keyword

```
public List<Student> GetStudentListByAge(int age){
foreach(Student s in Admin.GetStudentList()){
if(s.Age > age) yield return s;
                                            }
                                                 }
```

**Third Way**

using a local list:

```
public List<Student> GetStudentListByAge(int age){
List<Student> list2 = new List<Student>();
foreach(Student s in Admin.GetStudentList()){
if(s.Age > age) list2.Add(s);
                                            }
return list2;
                                                 }
```

So, i need to know what is the best way between it ? Why? in which cases?

Comment: why not using `Where` from LINQ?

Comment: Yes , it is another possibility.So i need which one is the best

Comment: best how? fastest? most readable? least likely to fail? what are your requirements and have you made any tests and trials to find out which one fits you best?

Comment: @Default : i need to know which one is fastest ie if the count of the elements of the list is big , which is the fastest to give the result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one is internally implemented as the third one. The second will not return `List<Student>` but `IEnumerable<Student>`.

I'd personally would use **LINQ** like :

`Admin.GetStudentList().Where(x => x.Age > 20).ToList()`

It's short and if `GetStudentList()` returns `IQueryable<Student>` in the future, you won't need to rewrite this code and moreover it will be more efficient than the others.

Answer (score 1):

The second way is the best because it uses yield and it's more general. And that is exactly how `Where` is implemented in LINQ to objects. So the real answer is use LINQ:

```
IEnumerable<Student> studentsByAge = Admin.GetStudentList().Where(x => x.Age > 20);
```

P.S: `FindAll` would also perform well in this case, but it belongs to list, which means that if you change the type to another collection you'll have to change that too.

Comment: it's not *exactly* like `Where`... `Where` doesn't take an int but a predicate as argument.

Answer (score 0):

in this case the one that is more readable more, portable and has less code.
witch are methods provided by linq such as "All", "Where", ...

```
        students.Where(s => s.FirstName == "s");
        students.All(s => s.Age > 10);
```